# VHDL syntax to output a signal value

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to learn the syntax of VHDL. I wrote a simple algorithm using a counter and an LED.
in the port section, I have...
LED         :       OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

Below port, I have...
signal cntr     :       natural range 0 to (2**30);

I have a process that increments cntr.

After the process, I have...
LED(7 downto 0) <= std_logic_vector (to_signed(cntr(29 downto 22)));

I am trying to blink the LEDs to show the count. I need help in the line above where I am trying to convert a signal to a std_logic_vector and match 8 bits with the LED.

Comment: That tries to access the individual bits of a natural (which isn't supported). You want `std_logic_vector (to_signed(cntr,32)(29 downto 22));` which converts to a 32-bit signed and indexes into the bits of that. As cntr is natural, a 31 bit unsigned would be a better choice. Or 30 bit if you reduce the range by 1.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].